# Scale_x_break creates multiple axis on the figure

Tags: scale

```
fig <- Ast090523 %>%
  mutate(Condition = factor(Condition)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ratio, y = Mean, color = Condition)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(size = 0.5)

fig

fig2 <- fig +
  scale_x_break(c(1, 2), scales = 0.3) +
  scale_x_reverse()

fig2
```

Hi, this is my code, and my figure has 2 x axis and overall 2y and 3 x axis. How to eliminate all but the inner axis.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBOlt.png)

I tried to put the scale_x_break inside the fig part, but it gave me the same result

Thank you